# Lock one row column in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Is it possible to lock one row column in Access after i update it? I try use AfterUpdate method but it is no work. Please help. Thanks. Sorry for English.

Comment: Please show your code?

Comment: `Private Sub PlanuojamaPristatymoData_AfterUpdate()
    Me.MyField.Enabled = False
End Sub` it disable all fields in column

Comment: Does the data have a primary key?

Comment: Yes, but i think method must be `BeforeUpdate()`

Comment: yes, but it will lock the column as suggested.

Comment: is this a datasheet on a form or the table?

Comment: it is in the form but looks like gridview

Comment: ok, you could track the pk of the updated record in a collection,array or table, then if the current record is within this collection, to move to next record, move to somewhere else etc.  So use afterupdate to add the PK for the changed record to the collection, then on current, check the collection for the PK of the current record.  I am no sure on the best way to tackle, i'll have a look in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public col As Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set col = New Collection
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    If CHANGED(Me.TeamID) Then
        MsgBox "not allowed"
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TeamName_AfterUpdate()
    col.Add CStr(Me.TeamID.value), CStr(Me.TeamID.value)
End Sub

Public Function CHANGED(strValue As String) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ehandle

        CHANGED = True
        Dim strTest As String
        strTest = col(strValue)

Exit Function

ehandle:

        CHANGED = False

End Function
```

This puts the PK of the table Teams TeamID from my database in a collection, then it checks to see if it's in the collection, i.e. it's been changed, if not then its ok, if it has been changed then it's "not allowed" message box.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't wok `function or sub is not defined (CHANGED)`

Comment: Are you sure you've entered it right?  The function is clearly defined there, Public Function CHANGED(strValue As String) As Boolean